# Use javascript with external website in iframe or div

Tags: jquery, iframe

I know we can't do that but I would like to know if there is another way to do the following thing :

```
<iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" height="100%" src="http://google.com"></iframe>

<script>
$(function(){
    $(document.body).bind('mouseup', function(e){
        var selection;

        if (window.getSelection) {
          selection = window.getSelection();
        } else if (document.selection) {
          selection = document.selection.createRange();
        }

        selection.toString() !== '' && alert('"' + selection.toString() + '" was selected at ' + e.pageX + '/' + e.pageY);
    });
});
</script>
```

So I want to do an action in the iframe. Open a popup with the selected text for example.

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible, if iframe src is different domain from parent container domain as in your code.

but if both domain are same then you can access dom of iframe.

for this you need to first access innerDoc of iframe by:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('html2');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

once you get the object, now you can access:

```
innerDoc.getElementById('divId');
```